# No sound with Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I cannot get sound working in the emulator in Android Studio. It's not my code as it's a very simple example program to demonstrate the `MediaPlayer` that works fine on an actual device.

On the emulator in Android Studio there is absolutely no sound, not even system sounds. Is this an Android/Android Studio bug? Or could it be the configuration of my particular system? Windows 10 issue?

Anyone else having this problem? Any solution other than using a real device or Genymotion (which I've never used) ?? Thanks.

EDIT: The only way I can get the emulator in Android Studio to start with audio is to launch it from the terminal with *both* the "-no-snapshot" and "-no-snapshot-load" options. And this only works about 80% of the time. It has something to do with snapshots. There are a couple of old questions on this but no solutions.

Comment: You don´t want to use Genymotion or you don´t know how to?

Comment: oh no, I'm about to try it ... just wondering about this particular issue and why it's happening and if anyone else is experiencing it

Comment: I was curious about this bug too. I looked in google for more info and can´t find anyone having this same problem. I can only wonder that it is something related to your sound board or something like that. In genymotion you was able to play the sound?

Comment: Once I get Genymotion installed and working I'll let you know

Comment: Wow. No sound in Genymotion either. It must be something about my particular PC configuration. I suspect Windows 10 has something to do with it as I never had this problem with Win7 ... I can *sometimes* get the sound back if I start the emulator in the terminal with the "-no-snapshot-load" option, but not always. How do I configure it to never use snapshots?

Comment: Full reinstall of Android Studio and the SDK didn't solve the problem.

Comment: do you have problems with sound in your computer with any other software? Can you check that the emulator has the volume high?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122597/discussion-between-shadowgod-and-jonathanrz).

Answer (score 4):

it seems that the problem has something to do with the emulator api  so changing the emulator api solved it for me and I guess it will do for you.

Comment: API 33 is screwed up, I tried API 31 and it worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: Exact same problem here. Switching from 33 back to 31 fixed it, as well as some other issues like needing to disable the custom device frame.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open your Oracle VM Virtualbox. Go to Settings -> Audio -> Host Audio Driver and change it to PulseAudio.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What does virtualbox have to do with Android Studio's emulator?

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, click the Volume Up button ([doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#tasks)).

[image]